# How can I correct the fact that text highlight colour different from item selection colour, in OSX and macOS since 2002?

Tags: finder, text, color, highlights

Is there a workaround or solution for the fact that Apple have made text highlight colour, in e.g. TextEdit and Preview (pdf with text) different from the colour used to highlight items in e.g. Finder and Activity Monitor.
The item selection colour is more saturated/muddier/darker.
A striking example is the difference between my preferred lemon Stabilo yellow (chosen from the colour wheel) for text which Apple couples to a nasty muddy mustard colour for item selection.
Amazingly few other complainants on net, but I have found one from 2002.
I've sent feedback to Apple, but no change or response, including up until 10.13 High Sierra Beta.

Are there workarounds or third-party apps to correct this unwanted colour disparity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s unclear if the question is on topic or just about an Apple decision / implementation choice. See the [ask] link for details

Comment: I've edited it to clarify that I am asking for info/help.